# R - Como calcular a variação de preço para diferentes períodos e empresas?

Tags: r, matemática, diff

Olá, gostaria de saber como calcular a variação de preços de um período para o outro. Sendo que são vários anos para várias empresas. Exemplo:

> Empresa | Ano | Preço
>
> 1       |2007 | 25
>
> 1       | 2008 | 30
>
> 1       |2009 | 7
>
> 1       |2010 | 15
>
> 2       |2007 | 20
>
> 2      | 2008 | 27
>
> 2       |2009 | 7
>
> 2       |2010 | 20

... |... |...|...

A nova coluna ficaria:

> Empresa | Ano | Preço | Variação
>
> 1       |2007 | 25 | 25-0 = 25
>
> 1       | 2008 | 30 | 30-25 = 5
>
> 1       |2009 | 7 | 7-30 = -23
>
> 1       |2010 | 15 | 15-7 = 8
>
> 2       |2007 | 20 | 20-0 = 20
>
> 2       | 2008 | 27 | 27-20 = 7
>
> 2            |2009 | 7 | 7-27 = -20
>
> 2            |2010 | 20 | 20-7 = 13
>
> ... |... |...|...

Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

daria para usar o diff?

Obrigado desde já !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função `ave` foi feita para resolver este tipo de problemas.

```
dados$Variação <- ave(dados$Preço, dados$Empresa, FUN = function(x) c(x[1], diff(x)))
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Empresa = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Ano = c(2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), Preço = c(25L, 30L, 
7L, 15L, 20L, 27L, 7L, 20L)), .Names = c("Empresa", "Ano", "Preço"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado !